# Is there a way to set default file information

Tags: cs5, adobe-creative-suite

Is there a way to set up Illustrator/Photoshop/InDesign CS5 with default file information?  What I want to do is set it so that I am the author of all of my work by default without having to change it in the "file information" panel each time.

Thanks in advance.

Eoin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set up a template, fill in the common info and then save the template, then just pick the template for future use.

[image: templates]

I don't believe there's a way to set metadata by default since each file is expected to be different.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll do that for a few different things :)

Answer (score 2):

I found the below Listening script great for adding metadata to my InDesign PDFs. I wanted the Author and Document Title included in the PDF Document Properties each time I generated a PDF as a default.

As a bonus I found this script also applies the same metadata (under File > File Info...) to every InDesign file I create by default. *You need to export as PDF first before the data appears in File Info...

You can customize as you like then copy into InDesign Startup Scripts folder and restart InDesign.

The original script was found in this thread: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1856961 I added the "author" data.

Hope this helps.

```
tell application "Adobe InDesign CC 2019"
    make event listener with properties {event type:"beforeExport", handler:addMeta}
end tell

on addMeta()
  tell application "Adobe InDesign CC 2019"
    tell active document
        -- the ID doc name
        set n to name
        -- the page count
        set p to count of pages
        --a list of visible layers
        set l to name of every layer whose visible is true
        set llist to ""
        repeat with x in l
            set llist to x & ", " & llist
        end repeat
        set llist to "Visible Layers: " & llist
        --the page count and layer list for the description field
        set ptext to "Document Page Count: " & p & "   " & llist as string
        set properties of metadata preferences to {author:"YOUR NAME", document title:n, description:ptext}
    end tell
  end tell
end addMeta
```